# Was Roald Dahl the first to use the "Hitler twist?"

Tags: history-of-literature, roald-dahl

In his story "Genesis and Catastrophe" [1959] , also called "A fine son", Roald Dahl uses a plot twist that has been done so often that it is an eye-roller: revealing near the end that the protagonist is Hitler.

Was he the first writer to use this plot device? Or did anyone beat him to it?